# Does Html.EditorFor support more than class in MVC5.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Without modifying my Editor Templates, is it possible to pass other HTML attributes into the `Html.EditorFor` Helper extension?

The example shows a class being passed in:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.information, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})
```

There are many potential scenarios but I want to decorate my input with a `data-myvar="value"`. When I try this I get compiler errors `invalid anonymous type declaratory`.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.information, new { htmlAttributes = new { @data-myvar="value" }})
```

Additionally if it is possible can I pass this in in addition to a class? i.e. pass in an array of `htmlattributes`. I'm struggling to find any documentation apart from the release notes.

[John Galaway's article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2014/01/28/looking-at-asp-net-mvc-5-1-and-web-api-2-1-part-3-bootstrap-and-javascript-enhancements.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does, but because of how .NET handles anonymous types (thanks Mark), you need to change the dash to an underscore.  Also the `@` symbol is only needed when you are declaring the class in the Html attributes dictionary (since class is a reserved word).  You can leave that off when declaring `data-` elements.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.information, 
      new { htmlAttributes = new { data_myvar="value" }})
```

When this is parsed by the helper, a dash will actually be rendered out in the HTML.

```
<input type="text" id="information" name="information" data-myvar="value"/>
```

To pass in multiple attributes, just separate the values by a comma

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.information, 
      new { htmlAttributes = new { data_myvar="value", data_othervar = "something" }})
```

Comment: awesome thanks, how do i pass in more than one attribute? i.e. an array?

Comment: Not strictly because of razor, but of any anonymous type.  The dash is not a valid character in any identifier

Comment: @MarkPeters - Updated addressing your comment as well

Comment: cheers @Tommy that works It might just be me but im finding with the new agile release methods of the asp.net team there seems to be less documentation. Barring a few examples. Asp.Net Identity is the perfect example in this i found.